# If all divs in section are hidden, hide the section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am displaying divs, inside a `section`.  There are multiple sections, and multiple child divs in each section.  I dynamically check a dropdown field, to hide the child divs if they don't match the selection in the dropdown.  This works great.

However, I now want to HIDE the entire section if all the divs in the section are hidden.  Here's my code:

JS

```
if ($("section .listings").length === $("section .listing.h_group").length){
    $('section').hide();
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- this section should hide -->
<section class="groups" style="clear:both;">
    <h2 class="group-name">Business Liner</h2>
    <div class="listings h_group></div>
    <div class="listings h_group></div>
    <div class="listings h_group></div>
    <div class="listings h_group></div>
</section>

<!-- This section should show -->
<section class="groups" style="clear:both;">
    <h2 class="group-name">Business Liner</h2>
    <div class="listings h_group></div>
    <div class="listings></div>
    <div class="listings h_group></div>
    <div class="listings></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.h_group {
    display:none;
}
```

The code currently returns an error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

It seems it's not finding the section, but I can't work out why.  I also think if this did work, it would hide every section, but I only want it to hide the section that has all its divs hidden.

Comment: when is this code executed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've a couple of issues here. Firstly your `class` attribute in the HTML is missing the closing quotes, so it won't be recognised properly. You need to add those quotes in. Secondly the class is `.listings`, not `.listing`

Lastly, you need to check each `section` element individually, not all of them at the same time. As such you will need to loop through them. Then you use `find()` to determine if there are any `:visible` child `.listing` elements and `toggle()` the section depending on the result. Try this:

```js
$('section').each(function() {
  $(this).toggle($(this).find('.listings:visible').length != 0);
});
```

```css
.h_group {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- this section should hide -->
<section class="groups" style="clear:both;">
  <h2 class="group-name">Business Liner #1</h2>
  <div class="listings h_group"></div>
  <div class="listings h_group"></div>
  <div class="listings h_group"></div>
  <div class="listings h_group"></div>
</section>

<!-- This section should show -->
<section class="groups" style="clear:both;">
  <h2 class="group-name">Business Liner #2</h2>
  <div class="listings h_group"></div>
  <div class="listings"></div>
  <div class="listings h_group"></div>
  <div class="listings"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The Syntax errors were down to me typing badly, I tried to simplify the code as it's a bit more complicated than this in practice.  That being said, the code you provided does still provide a 'null' value in the JS console...Says "cannot provide property 'each' of null...  It's as though the code isn't finding the section?

Comment: Ignore that last comment, I forgot I'm in Wordpress so needed 'jQuery' instead of $.  However it still does not seem to work.  No error message, it simply doesn't hide the section.  the h_group class is added via JS when the user selects a dropdown value - does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, that would make a difference. You'd need to run this code *after* the elements have been added to the DOM

Comment: How would I do that?  Can I implement some sort of listener for when the dropdown changes?

Comment: You could, but it would make more sense to just put the code above right after you call `append()`

Answer (score 1):

I see that your html has syntax errors i.e. the class attributes don't have ending quotes. Try adding ending quotes to all class attributes and i hope it will work fine. 
For the HTML provided above, i have added ending quotes. See below:

```
<section class="groups" style="clear:both;">
    <h2 class="group-name">Business Liner</h2>
    <div class="listings h_group"></div>
    <div class="listings h_group"></div>
    <div class="listings h_group"></div>
    <div class="listings h_group"></div>
</section>

<!-- This section should show -->
<section class="groups" style="clear:both;">
    <h2 class="group-name">Business Liner</h2>
    <div class="listings h_group"></div>
    <div class="listings"></div>
    <div class="listings h_group"></div>
    <div class="listings"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  If this was the only problem, then question should be voted closed as a typo.  (this *is* frequently the case, so a worthy observation).  When you have more reputation (50) you can request in the comments to confirm if the original code has the typo or if it's just been entered in the question incorrectly.